# Most efficient substring replacement in Java

Tags: java, hashmap

I am writing XML (JATS Standard) to LaTeX converter and am wondering what is the best way for escaping LaTeX special symbols. In my converter all data from XML is transferred to Java Object with setters and than is written to TeX file with getters.
Simple code for the object that contains text from Node as a String:

```
public class Par extends ParContent {
    private String parContent;

    public String getContent() {    
        return parContent;
    }

    public void setContent(String parContent) {
        this.parContent = parContent;

    }
}
```

What I need now is to replace symbols, that have special meaning in LaTeX. For this HashMap was used. Example:

```
public String replacement(String parContent) {
        HashMap<String, String> forReplacement = new HashMap<String, String> ();
        forReplacement.put("%", "\\%");
        forReplacement.put("±", "$\\pm$");
        forReplacement.put("<", "\\textless{}");
        forReplacement.put(">", "\\textgreater{}");
        //String parContent1 = null;
        for (Entry<String, String> entry : forReplacement.entrySet()) {
            if (parContent.contains(entry.getKey())) {
                parContent = parContent.replace(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
            }   
        }
        return parContent;
    }
```

Personally I have 2 questions:

- Is this most efficient way in terms of speed? There is a need a lot
  of symbols to replace.
- Is it better used with setter (while setting
  the value) or getter (while retrieving the value) or it makes no
  odds?

Comment: is speed a problem? Some things to consider, probably would make sense for the variable forReplacement to be a static field for easier reading.

There's really no reason for this data structure to be a map. it's really just a list of items with 2 values.

Comment: @Vitaly I would at least drop the `contains` and then `replace` and simply do a `replaceAll` instead

Comment: OK, will do, thanks